# Generating a random number of agents getting picked up in a transformation model [anylogic]

Tags: anylogic

I'm trying to generate a simulation for a food waste reduction organization that involves going to specific locations on a GIS map and both picking up and dropping off food items. I have data samples for specific amounts being picked up at each location, but I'm interested in assigning a random amount (likely will use the "triangular" command) within a specific range to be picked up.

Is there an optimal way to do this?

I've tried doing this with source/queue/pickup but have not had success. I've also tried setting the arrival rate in the source as the mean value of the sample but this doesn't feel like the best way to do this and the data from the simulation has been questionable when I've done this.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SOF and AnyLogic. This place works best for you if you ask very specific questions, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. Your question is far too broad and would need a full lecture to tell you all about it. I suggest you read up here to learn how to ask great questions: Use https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and this article focused on AnyLogic: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow . Treat us as very busy colleagues that are happy to help. The more effort you put into your question, the more likely you will get a reply :)

Comment: If your real question is "how do I pickup random amounts instead of fixed ones", pls edit the question and add details of your actual setup. Hard to help otherwise :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an optimal way to do this?

No, there are a million ways and it depends on what specifically you want to do

> but I'm interested in assigning a random amount (likely will use the "triangular" command) within a specific range to be picked up.

Sure, its up to you which distribution you want to use, see the wizard for it: https://anylogic.help/anylogic/stochastic/choose-pdf.html#choose-probability-distribution-wizard